I am generating QR codes in flask , then storing as binary then trying to display them on a different page. Images wont load,they are just small icon
I have generated some qr codes on one page and then stored them in a sqlite database in binary under the BLOB variable type. I have then successfully managed to open them and save them successfully from another file but every time I try to get it to be displayed on another page they wont display and instead are just shown by a little picture icon.
@users_blueprint.route('/profile')
@login_required
@requires_roles('user')
def profile():
    #connecting database 
    conn = sqlite3.connect("instance/lottery.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #current user id 
    current_user_id = current_user.id 
    #Query search for QR codes 
    cursor.execute("SELECT qr_code FROM banks WHERE user_id = ?",(current_user_id,))
    #fetch all rows
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    #empty array
    qr_codes_binary = []
    
    for row in rows:
        qr_codes_binary.append(row[0])


    Image_strings =[]
    for img in qr_codes1:
        buffered = BytesIO()
        img.save(buffered,format="PNG")
        img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode()
        Image_strings.append('data:image/png;base64,{}'.format(img_str))
   return render_template('users/profile.html', name=current_user.firstname, images = Image_strings)



This is the user/views.py file and this is the section for the profiles page where I want it to display these qr codes.
This next segment is the html page .
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<h1 class="title">Welcome, {{ name }}</h1>

<body>
    {% for img in images %}
        
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ img }}" alt = "QR CODE">
    {% endfor %}
</body>
{% endblock %}

And the stuff at the top of base.html is the following
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.min.css" />
</head>

I have tried so many different ways of formatting the data but every time it just displays the little icons. I am open to suggestion if there is a better way of doing this.
My banks/views.py is where I collect the data from user and then generate the qr code and then format it into binary to then be stored in the database
@banks_blueprint.route('/Banks')
@login_required
@requires_roles('user')
def banks():
    
    return render_template('users/qrgenerate.html')

@banks_blueprint.route('/qrgenerate',methods =['GET','POST'])
def qrgenerate():
    
    #create qrgenerate form object 
    form = BankForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        #hash all data points
        bankname = form.bankName.data
        #bankname = bcrypt.hashpw(bankname.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
        sortcode = form.sortCode.data
        #sortcode = bcrypt.hashpw(sortcode.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
        accountnum = form.accountNumber.data
        #accountnum = bcrypt.hashpw(accountnum.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())

        #Format qr code data 
        additional_data = {"sortcode":form.sortCode.data,"accountnumber":form.accountNumber.data}
        encoded_data = "&".join([f"{key}={value}" for key,value in additional_data.items()])
        full_url = f"{payment_page_url}?{encoded_data}"

        #Generate qr code and store as binary
        qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1,error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,box_size =10,border=4)
        qr.add_data(full_url)
        qr.make(fit=True)
        #img is the qr code 
        img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black",back_color="white")
        #converting to binary 
        buffer = BytesIO()
        img.save(buffer,format='PNG')
        img_binary = buffer.getvalue()
        buffer.close()
        print(img_binary)
        print("*************************")
        img_binary = sqlite3.Binary(img_binary)
        print(img_binary)
        new_bankentry = Bank(user_id = current_user.id,sortCode = form.sortCode.data,accountNumber = form.accountNumber.data,bankName=form.bankName.data,qr_code=img_binary)
         
        db.session.add(new_bankentry)
        db.session.commit()
        
        #goes through so direct to profile page 
        return redirect(url_for('users.profile'))
    # if request method is GET or form not valid re-render signup page
    return render_template('banks/qrgenerate.html', form=form)

Iv triple checked them both and I cant really see a reason as to why the images wont display.
Any help is appreciated even if that telling me iv done it all wrong and should attempt it a different way .
I have tried to format it into base64 which the html should like and display the image but instead it just shows me the little picture icon . I have tried it a million ways with chat gpt but it cant seem to isolate the problem. I am using chrome to display the web app if that's making a difference. There are obviously other files in my program which I can show anyone if needed.

You seem to add data:image/png;base64, twice.
